# Get an averange of visitors in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to have an averange of visitors per day. I'm using Laravel 4.

The database structure I have is this:

> Name: `visitor`

[image: Structure]

Now I tried to use the avg() function of Laravel, but I can't find a right solution. Could someone help me please with this?

I already have an controller wich one looks like this:

```
public function index()
    {

        //$select_stats = Visitor::where('visit_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())->get();

        $begin = date('Y-m-01');
        $end = date('Y-m-t');

        $visits = Tracker::selectRaw('date, count(ip)')->groupBy('date')->whereRaw("date between '$begin' and '$end'")->get();

        //get total visits per month
        $get_visits = Visitor::whereRaw("date between '$begin' and '$end'")->count();

        //get averange visits


        return View::make('admin.home.index')->with('stats', $visits)->with('get_visits', $get_visits)/*->with('get_avg_visits', $get_avg_visits)*/;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you've got everything you need for calculating the average count of visitors, no additional query needed :) You just have to divide the total number of visits by the number of days of the month:

```php
public function index()
{
    $begin = date('Y-m-01');
    $end = date('Y-m-t');

    // ...

    //get total visits per month
    $get_visits = Visitor::whereRaw("date between '$begin' and '$end'")->count();

    // get average visits
    // transform dates to DateTime objects (we need the number of days between $begin and $end)
    $begin = new \DateTime($begin);
    $end = new \DateTime($end);
    $diff = $end->diff($begin); // creates a DateInterval object
    $days = (int)$diff->format('%a'); // %a  -->  days

    $average_visits = $get_visits / $days;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this-

```
$avrage_visit= Visitor::select(DB::raw('avg("date") as date_avg')))->groupBy('date')
  ->get();
```

Reference -
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

Comment: I want the average, not an total count.

Comment: Now I got an output like this: ` [{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0},{"date_avg":0}]`